# How to load a string from strings.xml inside webview class

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a class to load webpage:

```
 webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.login_view);
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

I want to load a string from strings.xml instead of `http://google.com`. How can I do this ?

Comment: You want to get the url from the resources `strings.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your current code to this

```
 webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.login_view);
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 webView.loadUrl(getResources().getString(R.string.url));
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do that

```
String url = getResources().getString(R.string.url);
```